# How to Read specific column value from .text file in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I am starting to work with `wso2` esb from few days back.
I need to read particular column value and set into property in wso2 esb.

My `.txt` file contains following values:

```
**SNO|FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|EMAIL|PHONE|ADDRESS|SELLING_DEALER**
**51|christopher|chris|cpko78@gmail.com|0406-755909|US|MacGgor**
```

I need to read email and phone column value from this .txt file and set into property which can be used for further operations like `EmailValidation` or `PhoneValidation`.
Can anyone help me out to fine solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ESB one option would be to do a smooks transformation into xml and then read the values from the generated xml. Just keep in mind that if you need the original csv content later in your proxy/api, you need to store the original content and restore it after you've read the needed values (using enrich mediator).

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Smooks+Mediator

Another option would be to do a xslt transformation into xml (similar to smooks).

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/XSLT+Mediator

The last option I could think of is using the script mediator and extract the values using JavaScript, Groovy, or Ruby.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Script+Mediator

If you use EI then you also might expose your csv as a data service.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS351/Exposing+CSV+Data+as+a+Data+Service

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Martin,
Thanks for your Information.I am gothrough   Link which you shared before in WSO2 Documentation.But I am not able to find exact Solution.Would you please show me the code snippet as soon as you can?Thank you so much...